# Add string to xPath in Selenium

Tags: python, string, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to add a string to a find by element xpath in Selenium

```
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Room 227 4:30 AM')]/..")
```

The part where it says "Room 227 4:30 AM" need to be such that I can add my own thing.
I tried to do this and it gave me a weird string is not a valid xpath

```
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'+newroomtime+')]/..")
```

newroomtime is a string

```
newrooomtime = 'Room 228 1:00 AM'
```

Comment: Seems you mismatch single and double quote marks. May be you should do something like `"//label[contains(text(),'"+newroomtime+"')]/.."`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations). Put a placeholder `%s` into the xpath string and fill it with a variable value:

```
xpath = "//label[contains(text(),'%s')]/.." % newrooomtime
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

Demo:

```
>>> newrooomtime = 'Room 228 1:00 AM'
>>> xpath = "//label[contains(text(),'%s')]/.." % newrooomtime
>>> xpath
"//label[contains(text(),'Room 228 1:00 AM')]/.."
```

Answer (score 0):

alecxe's answer is functionally correct, but you can do both things in the same line unless I am mistaken, which makes for cleaner code since you don't need to define a variable you will only use once.

Instead of:

```
xpath = "//label[contains(text(),'%s')]/.." % newroomtime
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

I would use:

```
box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[contains(text(),"%s")]/..' % newroomtime)
```

Additionally, I try not to stick driver.find_element actions into variables unless I really want to compare them to something else. This is again a question of keeping your code clean of unneeded extra variables.

Comment: I don't see any problem at all using as you call it unneeded variables. It is easier to read and therefore a good practice.